# Solve for $\theta$ in$\sqrt 3 \csc \theta =2 $

Tags: trigonometry

I got $\dfrac{1}{\sin(\theta)}=\dfrac{2\sqrt {3}}{3}$ then $\sin (\theta) = \dfrac{2\sqrt {3}}{3}$

The question is that the answer is not in the Unit circle I believe I made a error in my problem.

Comment: I think you inverted wrong - should be $\sin\theta = \sqrt{3}/{2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sqrt 3 \csc\theta = 2 \iff \csc \theta = \frac{2}{\sqrt 3} \iff \frac 1{\sin \theta} = \frac 2{\sqrt 3}$$

$$\iff \sin\theta = \frac{\sqrt 3}2 \implies \theta =\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right)$$

Comment: The solution should be $\theta = n\pi +(-1)^n \sin^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2},\,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ since the problem does not restrict $\theta$ to be in any specific interval.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac1{\sin \theta} = \dfrac{2 \cdot\sqrt3}{3}$ or $\sin \theta =\dfrac{3}{2\cdot \sqrt 3}$.

Now, divide the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt 3$.